# get port number of stream server on client side [running on heroku]

Tags: heroku, websocket, dart

I am trying to deploy my dart application on heroku but even when i have got my stream server running in the dyno, i don't have any idea as to how can i get the port number on client side code to connect to the server via websocket. Since i cannot use `Platform.environment['PORT']`, i don't know how to get the port.

My client side websocket address is this:

```dart
var port = '<The port number i need>';
var url = 'ws://0.0.0.0:$port/ws';
```

It has taken a lot of effort to deploy successfully to heroku. Please tell me that there is a way to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the link given by Gunter [Why won't my app establish websocket connection on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754922/why-wont-my-app-establish-websocket-connection-on-heroku), it just happens to be that the client side doesn't require an actual port to connect.

Doing the window.location.origin and replacing http:// with ws:// did the trick! Although problem is that even when my database opens up and all, there's some problem when using objectory to query upon it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Heroku myself yet but here the [doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing) says

> The Heroku platform automatically routes HTTP requests sent to your app’s > hostname(s) to your web dynos. The entry point for all applications on >the Cedar stack is the herokuapp.com domain which offers a direct routing path to your web dynos.

It should be possible to make a HTTP request to the hostname of your web dyno to connect to your server and your server should be able to do the `Platform.environment['PORT']` and report the result back.

Comment: Request to web dyno as in  request to http://xxxx.herokuapp.com or something else?

Comment: As I said, I don't know Heroku and there isn't much information how your application looks like but what I gathered there has to be a hostname your app can be reached at (the URL you enter into your browser to load your client). Here is a Node.js example how to use WebSocket. This should apply as well to Dart with just a bit different syntax https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets

Comment: This seems also similar to your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754922

Comment: Is there any place to deploy full stack dart app other than heroku or appengine? One which is easy to do and can serve both client and server side? Where do u deploy your apps? My dart app comprises of objectory + angulardart + rikulo stream

Comment: Thank u for posting that link... I'll definitely try it :)

Comment: I'm still working to get my Dart app in a deployable state but had successful experiments with AppEngine. You can use a dedicated server but this leads just to other problems you have to cope with yourself. I won't say Dart on AppEngine is easy. It's just experimental yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try " heroku run bash " and run your server in terminal then you can easily find your port in which your app  is running.