# SocketIO is not working in Heroku Environment [Works in Localhost]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, socket.io

I developed chat program with NodeJS and SocketIO. Then I deployed to Heroku Server  and I found that SocketIO is not working in Heroku.

I already checked the log in Heroku but there are nothing. But it is weird that it is working in localhost but not in Heroku environment. I think there are some problem with PORT Setting.

**[Server Side Code]**

```
/* Socket IO Settings */
const server = require('http').Server(express);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
let port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`SocketIO Listening on port : ${port}`)
});
```

**[Client Side Code]**

```
/* Chat Functions */
var socket = io.connect(`${window.location.hostname}:3001`);
```

At first time I just use `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001');` code and it works well in Localhost Env. But after I deployed to heroku I add Heroku Variable to use it in production.

**[PORT Setting]**

```
NODEJS Server : 3000
SOCKET IO : 3001
Heroku process.env.PORT : 3001 (But When I check Heroku console it changes everytime when I reload the dynos and in Logs said me that the ports are already in use.)
```

I already read Heroku Document but it seems that I create NodeJS App with Express Generator I think it should be different solution. I already tried heroku document but it's not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get port number of stream server on client side \[running on heroku\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227534/get-port-number-of-stream-server-on-client-side-running-on-heroku) Your problem is that your heroku dyno is not exposed on port 3001, but internally on some random port, and externally on port 80. This thread should get you where you need to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your server ip in server.listen function

```
var ip='127.0.0.1';
var port ='3001' ;
server.listen(ip,port, function() {console.log('server stsrt in ip: ' +ip+' and port: ' +port);}) ;
```