# Heroku nodejs websocket server returning 503?

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket, server

**This is solved, I can't mark my own answer yet but it's solved!**

So I'm trying to host a nodejs server on Heroku, the server works fine when I host it local, the problem is that whenever I try to connect using:

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://<myapp>.herokuapp.com');
```

I get an error in the heroku logs:

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=<myapp>.herokuapp.com request_id=<request-id> fwd="<my-ip>" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

I have no clue how to fix this, and I can't find anything on google. If someone understands this better then I do, please tell me what I'm doing wrong.
Here is my server code btw:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: PORT });

console.log("Listening on %d", PORT);

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
  console.log('received: %s', message);
});

ws.send('something');
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't my app establish websocket connection on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754922/why-wont-my-app-establish-websocket-connection-on-heroku).

Comment: Also, `process.env.PORT | 3000` should be `process.env.PORT || 3000`

Comment: @RobertMoskal I tried that, and got ` !    Couldn't find that feature.`

Comment: @robertklep I tried that aswell, but it didn't make a difference since it still logged this: `app[worker.1]: Listening on 28040`

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it somehow,
I simply recreated my application (on heroku) and it worked for some reason, pretty weird but Its solved.